Spilling of CPU logical registers
From what I understand, modern compilers:

Target or generate code that address logical registers which are dynamically renamed or mapped to physical/hardware registers at runtime; and there are more physical registers than logical registers.

Spill registers to stack memory when the program requires more registers than are available, and spilling is basically a write or store to memory instruction.


It seems to me that a compiler spilling logical registers solely based on the number of logical registers is very suboptimal -- unless the CPU can ignore spill instructions when a sufficient number of physical registers are available. Or do CPU-specific compilation flags such as gcc's -march=native help reduce spilling somehow? Or perhaps I don't understand enough about what physical registers are for.

Register renaming is something modern CPUs do internally - a CPU may have more register available than can be addressed directly via the instruction set, but the compiler only has the instruction set at its disposal for expressing what the CPU should do.

@500-InternalServerError That much I know. The question is why does the compiler spill when it does not have the "full picture"? And how does the CPU cope with what seems to be unnecessary spilling, if indeed the spilling is unnecessary.

What do you suggest the compiler could do differently?

Nothing really. I am just wondering why generating and spilling instruction on the assumption that there are only 16 or so (logical) registers makes sense when there may in be in fact 64 (physical) registers. Or am I missing something here?

There is no way for the compiler to refer to those (here) 48 extra registers, so once it faces a situation where a register is needed but all the conventional ones are in use, what is the compiler to do, other than spill a register to a stack slot? --- If the instruction set could be modified to accommodate more registers, then register renaming (probably) wouldn't be a thing, but doing that would break code compatibility between different generations of chips.


It seems to me that a compiler spilling logical registers solely based
on the number of logical registers is very suboptimal -- unless the
CPU can ignore spill instructions when a sufficient number of physical
registers are available.

You are mistaken. Spilling is dependent on the number of physical registers. When the compiler uses up all of the available physical registers, it must spill a register to get another available physical register. Nested loops with arrays can use a lot of registers.

As I understand it, the compiler cannot know the number of physical registers at compile time. How can it? Therefore it targets logical registers and makes decisions on spilling at compile time. These lecture notes seem to suggest that is the case.  Intel APX (coming soon) should make more registers visible to the compiler.

An AOT compiler that generates native code knows its target ISA, so it knows how many physical registers there are at compile time.

Logical registers must be replaced by physical registers before the the target code is executed. Spillage occurs at this time.

I didn't know about AOT compilation (thanks). I can see how a JIT compiler can use knowledge of hot loops to decide which registers to spill.
